# Composite Keys for 3 Fields

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am creating an Oracle DB to keep track of jobs ran every day at a certain time and the time the job finishes running. I am having trouble with duplicate jobs showing up in the DB. Thinking of having a composite key with Job Name, Date Ran, and Time it finished ending. This will prevent the job from being posted multiple times as I check throughout the day for the other jobs. Anything wrong with this?

Comment: Looks ok a plan. And then you can combine date & time too.

Comment: @access_granted How would the insertion query look, new to backend stuff. Also, I do not want to combine the date and time so I can query it later down the line for specific dates / months at a time.

Comment: insert job_name, SYSTIMESTAMP into meta_jobs_table; Also, you can format datetime (or timestamp) to include just date or just time or both.

Comment: @access_granted the time stamp / date are already pre determined. Im pulling the files from a text file on a server (sadly its the way they've always done it) I just want to create a history of these jobs as the text file doesn't hold months worth of information. Thanks!